# Why linux kernel has. S and. C, how do they get to work together

Tags: linux, assembly, linux-kernel

As seen in this link 
https://elixir.bootlin.com/linux/v4.0/source/arch/x86/kernel/entry_64.S#
And also in this image of the kernel source code for x86 interact[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/u2Elb.png)

Comment: This is not kernel specific. `.S` contains assembly code and `.C` contains C source code.

Comment: Both C and assembly codes can be used to generate object files, then these object files can be linked together.

Answer (score 0):

Some part of Linux kernel, especially the bootloader will use some assembly language. The best way to knwo how they work together is to debug the code, and follow the start step by step. Here is a helpful [bolg](https://www.kernel.org/doc/html/latest/dev-tools/gdb-kernel-debugging.html). What's more, there is a [blog](https://gcc.gnu.org/onlinedocs/gcc/Using-Assembly-Language-with-C.html#:~:text=6.47%20How%20to%20Use%20Inline,includes%20one%20or%20more%20operands.) can give you some knowledge about how they work.